# run php file on button click ajax

Tags: php, ajax

**Entry level user here.** I've seen countless AJAX\PHP examples with data being passed via POST or GET and modified one of their examples. When clicking the button (id="clickMe) I want it to execute advertise.php and nothing more (no variables need to be passed) without refreshing the page and a notification that says success. When I click the button with my current code nothing happens.

```
<button type="button" id="clickMe">CLICK ME TO RUN PHP</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clickMe').click(function(event){ // capture the event
event.preventDefault(); // handle the event
$.ajax({
    url: 'advertise.php',
    data: {
        'ajax': true
    }, 
    success: function(data) {
        $('#data').text(data);
    }
});
});
});
</script>
```

**Updated, but still isn't executing.**

Comment: try to add `$(function(){` at first then your script and at the end `})`

Comment: Try writing you script after the button.

Comment: thanks for all the tips!

Comment: Kiran it still isn't working. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried what I supplied in my answer @michelle?

Comment: Jay I just did now. No luck. I updated my example above according to what you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your editted version code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $.post("PHP_FILE.php",{ajax: true},function(data, status){
             alert(data);
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: No. It down voted instantly. Maybe somebody were trying to get a new badge. :D

Comment: I didn't DV but the likely explanation is that a.) it didn't handle the click event as the OP asked and b.) has no explanation for what is done. A post containing only code is not considered to be a "good" answer no matter how accurate it may be.Many code only answers are typically commented on with something like, "Why should the OP try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO."

Comment: I updated my code as you suggested (see above), but it's still not executing. Any idea what would be the issue?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe it needs          event.preventDefault();

Comment: As I use this in my projects. It doesn't need that. Can you test the document.ready and your click function with putting some alerts in them?

Comment: Oh wow. Sorry for wasting your time. For some reason Ad Block Plus was preventing it from executing. I wonder if there's a way to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

2 things - you need a document ready handler and to prevent the default click action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').click(function(event){ // capture the event
         event.preventDefault(); // handle the event
         $.ajax({ // remainder of code...
});
```

When loading jQuery scripts at the top of the page you need to make sure they do not run until the DOM has loaded, that is what the document ready handler is for. The you capture the click event by including it as an argument for your click's callback function and handle the click with the `preventDefault()` method.

Since this request is "simple" you may want to consider using one of the shorthand methods, like [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: ops, excuse me. mistakenly posted here. Removed.